# Github API: Is it possible to list Pull Requests by label?

Tags: github-api

I've been looking through the API docs, but I was unable to find a way to accomplish that. Thought I'd ask here in case anyone knows. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Search Issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) API endpoint:

- Use the `repo` keyword to filter by repo (e.g. [`repo:ionicabizau/scrape-it`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/scrape-it))
- Use the `is:pr` to filter the pull requests (note that pull requests are issues, but issues are *not* pull requests)
- Use the `label` keyword to filter by label: `label:your-label`

Example:

> [`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:pr%20label:enhancement%20repo:ionicabizau/scrape-it`](https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:pr%20label:enhancement%20repo:ionicabizau/scrape-it)

Answer (score 0):

Use [GitHub CLI (gh)](https://cli.github.com/manual/index) like this `gh api 'search/issues?q=repo:your-org/your-repo+is:pr+label:your-label'`